# Database modeling: best aproach for multiple categories for multiple elements

Tags: php, mysql, database, modeling

Let's say I have 10 books, each book has assigned some categories (ex. :php, programming, cooking, cookies etc).

After storing this data in a DB I want to search the books that match some categories, and also output the matched categories for each pair of books.

What would be the best approach for a fast and easy to code search:

1) Make a column with all categories for each book, the book rows would be unique (categs separated by comma in each row ) -> denormalisation from 1NF

2) Make a column with only 1 category in each row and multiple rows per book

I think it is easier for other queries if I store the categories 1 by 1 (method 2), but harder for that specific type of search. Is this correct?

I am using PHP and MySQL.

PPS : I know multi relational design, I prefer not joining every time the tables. I'm using different connection for some tables but that's not the problem. I'm asking what's the best approach for a db design for this type of search: a user type cooking, cookies, potatoes and I want to output pairs of books that have 1,2 more or all matched categs. I'm looking for a fast query, or php matching technique for this thing... Tell me your pint of view. Hope I'm understood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use method 2 -- multiple rows per book, storing one category per row.  It's the only way to make searching for a given category easy.

This design avoids [repeating groups within a column](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Repeating_groups_within_columns), so it's good for First Normal Form.

But it's not just an academic exercise, it's a practical design that is good for all sorts of things.  See my answer to [Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: Yes 80% i agree with ur post linked... but as u said... sometimes maybe u need denormalisation... i know its better for alot more queries to stick to the normalisation rules , but that type of search will be very annoying to querie...anyway i gues it will be up to me to choose... and i think ill stick with method 2 like u all said. Ty

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is have one table for books, one table for categories, and one table for connecting books and categories. Something like this:

**books**

```
book_id | title | etc
```

**categories**

```
category_id | title | etc
```

**book_categories**

```
book_id | category_id
```

This is called a many-to-many relationship. You should probably google it to learn more.

Comment: if I only have a few categories, would creating a categories table be somewhat overkill? what about storing just a string?

Comment: I would definitely still recommend using a separate table for categories.

Answer (score 2):

This relationship is a Many-To-Many (a book can have multiple categories and a category can be used in several books).

Then we have the following:

[image: Diagram]

Got it?

=]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend approach number 2. This is because approach 1 requires a full text search of the category column.

You may have some success by splitting it up into two tables: One table has one line per book and a unique id (call the table `books`), and the other has one line per book per category and references the book id from the first table (call the table `bookcategories`). Then if you only need book data you use table `books`, where if you need categories you `join` both tables.

Comment: like a said i use unique connection for some tables/ queries... joining tables ruins every bit of sercurity added...but yea ur right

Comment: How does `join` ruin security?

Comment: lets say u have a different connection for 2 tables... by joining them u can use only 1 connection... and if that connection used for the joined querie is compromissed it will make vulnerable both tables. u understand now?